# New column using apply function on other columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a dataframe where three of the columns are coordinates of data ('H_x', 'H_y' and 'H_z'). I want to calculate radius-vector of the data and add it as a new column in my dataframe. But I have some kind of problem with pandas apply function.
My code is:

```
def radvec(x, y, z):
    rv=np.sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)
    return rv

halo_field['rh_field']=halo_field.apply(lambda row: radvec(row['H_x'], row['H_y'], row['H_z']), axis=1)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
group_sh.py:78: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
halo_field['rh_field']=halo_field.apply(lambda row: radvec(row['H_x'], row['H_y'], row['H_z']), axis=1)
```

I get column that I want, but I'm still confused with this error message.
I'm aware there are similar questions here, but I couldn't find how to solve my problem. I'm fairly new to python. Can you help?

**Edit:** `halo_field` is a slice of another dataframe:

```
halo_field = halo_res[halo_res.N_subs==1]
```

Comment: How have you defined `halo_field` *earlier* in your code? Most likely it's a *slice* of another dataframe and *that's* the cause of your error.

Comment: Yes, it is, it's slice of another dataframe: halo_field=halo_res[halo_res.N_subs==1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're working with a slice, which can be ambiguous:

```
halo_field = halo_res[halo_res.N_subs==1]
```

You have two options:

#### Work on a copy

You can explicitly copy your dataframe to avoid the warning and ensure your original dataframe is unaffected:

```
halo_field = halo_res[halo_res.N_subs==1].copy()
halo_field['rh_field'] = halo_field.apply(...)
```

#### Work on the original dataframe conditionally

Use [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with a Boolean mask to update your original dataframe:

```
mask = halo_res['N_subs'] == 1
halo_res.loc[mask, 'rh_field'] = halo_res.loc[mask, 'rh_field'].apply(...)
```

#### Don't use `apply`

As a side note, in *either* scenario you can avoid `apply` for your function. For example:

```
halo_field['rh_field'] = (halo_field[['H_x', 'H_y', 'H_z']]**2).sum(1)**0.5
```

Comment: Yes, that works, I'll be going with working on a copy! Thank you so very much. I'm sorry I can't upvote your answer, as a new user I don't have enough reputation.